# Making a basic algorithm - the more interesting version

Tags: java, algorithm

*See the edit history of ["Making a basic algorithm"](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36601340/revisions). There was a palpable sense of disappointment amongst the respondents when OP changed the question, invalidating some interesting answers. So, I figure, why not ask the original question again, to allow those answers to stand.*

> So basically I want to find a easier way to do this:
>
> ```
> if(size == 2)  unit /= 2;
> if(size == 2 || size == 6) unit /= 2;
> if(size == 2 || size == 6 || size == 10) unit /= 2;
> ```
>
> So basically it checking if size is equal to 2 and then every new line it add 4 to the last size check.
>
> I need to go up to 256.
>
> I want to know if there a easy way of doing this.

Comment: I applaud you for doing this.

Comment: Can you give this a descriptive title or description so that it might be useful to someone in the future? No one who is searching "basic algorithm" is ever going to come across this.

Comment: @Mike any suggestions?

Comment: Since you answered your own question I have to assume you have some understanding of it. My suggestion is to follow the SO guidelines about being specific with the problem, or simply close/delete the question if it's so niche and confounding that you cannot do that.

Answer (score 9):

The fundamental criterion on the numbers checked for equality here is that the remained of `size / 4` is 2. This can be detected using the modulo operator, `%`:

```
size % 4 == 2
```

Then there is the question of how many times to divide `unit` by 2. For the examples above:

- For `size == 2`, `unit /= 8` (matches all 3 conditions);
- For `size == 6`, `unit /= 4` (matches second 2 conditions);
- For `size == 10`, `unit /= 2` (matches last condition).

So the smaller the number, the more times it is divided by 8. If the maximum `size` checked is 10, `unit` is divided by `2 ^ (1 + (10 - size) / 4)`. This can be expressed concisely using the right-shift operator:

```
unit >>= 1 + (10 - size) / 4
```

or, more generally:

```
unit >>= 1 + (max_number - size) / 4
```

where `max_number % 4 == 2`.

Setting `max_number = 254` (256 is specified in the question, but wouldn't feature in the expression; the last number checked would be 254), and noting that we only apply this if `2 <= size <= 254`, we can express the final answer as:

```
if (size % 4 == 2 && size >= 2 && size <= 254) {
  unit >>= 1 + (254 - size) / 4;
}
```

Actually, the condition can be expressed more concisely (but undoubtedly less readably) as:

```
if ((size & 0xffffff03) == 2)
```

---

As noted by @PaulBoddington, care needs to be taken with the size of the right shift: if unit is an `int` and the number of bits shifted is greater than 31, then `unit` should simply be set to zero.

Comment: This depends on the type of `unit`. If `unit` is an `int`, shift amounts are read modulo 32, so you'd have to do `int p = 1 + (254 - size) / 4; unit = p > 31 ? 0 : unit >> p;`.

Comment: @PaulBoddington very true.